# Temporary port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port, iptables, portforwarding

For family tech support hell (tm) I'm getting into ssh.

My plan:

- Forward port 5022 to 5022 in router.
- `them@theircomputer$ ssh -L 5022:localhost:22 localhost`
- `me@mycomputer$ ssh -p 5022 them@theircomputer`

Result: `ssh: connect to host theircomputer port 5022: Connection refused`

It seems obvious ssh tunneling is supposed to tunnel requests not listens.

I don't want to give them ssh access to my system to set up a reverse tunnel that way.

I don't want to forward port 5022 to port 22 and I don't want to make ssh listen to port 5022 permanently (For security)

How do I temporarily forward port 5022 to port 22 on a system? (Preferably in a short oneliner!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more googling lead to the ssh flag `-g`

```
    -g      Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
```